# Playing mp3 files in android application

Tags: android, sms, mp3, playback

I am making an android application that will play an mp3 file once a sms containing "PhoneAlarm" is received.
This is the final code that works for me.

Note that: "I will not use all of the coding that's in here"
Take a look at my code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.telephony.gsm.SmsMessage;
import android.widget.DigitalClock;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;

public class IncomingSmsCaptureApp extends BroadcastReceiver {
MediaPlayer mp1;
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

//Get the text file
File file = new File(sdcard,"Notes\file.txt");

//Read text from file
String text = new String();

try {
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
  String line;

  while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
  }
}
catch (IOException e) {
  //You'll need to add proper error handling here
}
//---get the SMS message passed in---
Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();       
SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
String str = "";     
String Message = "";
if (bundle != null)
{
//---retrieve the SMS message received---
Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];           
for (int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++){
msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);               
str += "SMS from " + msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();                    
str += " :";
str += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
str += "\n";       
Message = msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
}
//---display the new SMS message---
Toast.makeText(context, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
if (Message == "PhoneAlarm") {
//Play alarm sound
mp1 = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.alarm);
mp1.start();
}
}       
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `setDataSource()` method expects a string path to the media file, not just a resource id, you can create it using the [`create(context, resid)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#create%28android.content.Context,%20int%29) instead, and it will be ready to play your sound:

```
//When creating your player:
mp1 = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.alarm);

//When playing sound, note that prepare() should not be called:
mp1.start();

//When you don't need the player anymore:
mp1.release();
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks so much but it's still not playing my sound once i receive a message. Please take a look at the code now.

Comment: That is because you are comparing Message and "PhoneAlarm" using the == operator, call Message.equals("PhoneAlarm") instead (which compares the content of the string, == just compares the objects, there have been lots of questions about this if you want to read more details about it). Also, as you are creating a new MediaPlayer everytime you play the sound, you should remember to call the release() method on it too.

Comment: You MADE me day! Thanks SO much! It works now!:-) But how about writing to the SD-Card so that it can read it???

Comment: You are welcome, remember to mark the answer as a correct answer to 'close' the question (click the checkmark to the left of the answer). You can create a new question for the sd-card stuff, but you'll need the permission WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, and then use a FileOutputStream ;)